# Dash multi-page app using DBC navigation bar

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dash-bootstrap-components, multi-page-application

I'm trying to replicate "multi_page_example1" from https://github.com/AnnMarieW/dash-multi-page-app-demos/tree/main. This uses a drop-down menu to navigate to different pages.

However, I want to adjust the navbar options to be the standard links as in the first example here: https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/navbar/

A simple example is below:

**Folder structure**:

```
- app.py
- app_pages
   |-- home.py
   |-- data_upload.py
   |-- __init__.py
```

**home.py**:

```
import dash
from dash import html

dash.register_page(__name__, path = '/')

layout = html.Div(children=[
        html.H1(children='This is our Home page')

])
```

**data_upload.py**:

```
import dash
from dash import html

dash.register_page(__name__)

layout = html.Div(children=[
        html.H1(children='This is our upload page')
])
```

**app.py**:

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash

app = dash.Dash(__name__, 
                pages_folder = "app_pages",
                use_pages = True, 
                external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

navbar = dbc.NavbarSimple(
            children=[
                dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("Home", href="/home")),
                dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("Data upload", href="/data_upload")),
            ],
            brand="Multipage Dash App",
            color="dark",
            dark=True,
            className="mb2",
            )

app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [navbar, dash.page_container],
    fluid = True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

**Problems**:

1. I have to run the app with "`debug=False`" because the server won't launch Dash otherwise.
2. When it launches I can see the basic web app with navbar links. However, clicking between pages generates a "404 - Page not found" message. Oddly, the home page displays the normal message initially, but the 404 after clicking between links.

Where am I going wrong?

This is my first time working with bootstrap components and Dash multi-page approaches. I'm hoping to re-configure my current tabs-only Dash web app to a multi-page app with tab layouts in individual pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Here's a simple single `app.py` file example demonstrating  a multi-page Dash web app

##### For example, using the code you provide and combining it into a single file:

> <sup>***Note***: You can of course extend this approach with >1 files, as you wish, so long as ensuring correct modularization & importing (e.g., of the `dash.Dash` app object, separate page layouts, callbacks, etc.).</sup>

Below, the layouts for the "Home" and "Data upload" pages are defined within the same file along with a callback that updates the '`page-content`' container based on the current URL path via `dcc.Location`.

```py
from dash import Dash, Input, Output
from dash import html, dcc

import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

home_layout = html.Div(children=[html.H1(children="This is our Home page")])

data_upload_layout = html.Div(
    children=[html.H1(children="This is our upload page")]
)

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

navbar = dbc.NavbarSimple(
    children=[
        dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("Home", href="/")),
        dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("Data upload", href="/data_upload")),
    ],
    brand="Multipage Dash App",
    color="dark",
    dark=True,
    className="mb-2",
)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Location(id="url", refresh=False),
        navbar,
        dbc.Container(id="page-content", className="mb-4", fluid=True),
    ]
)


@app.callback(Output("page-content", "children"), Input("url", "pathname"))
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == "/":
        return home_layout
    elif pathname == "/data_upload":
        return data_upload_layout
    else:
        return dbc.Jumbotron(
            [
                html.H1("404: Not found", className="text-danger"),
                html.Hr(),
                html.P(f"The pathname {pathname} was not recognized..."),
            ]
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

→ produces this app behavior:

[image: Video screen recording showing functionality of example demo dash app]

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the response and the solution. On a small scale this would work, in which case I accept your answer as the solution. My code base at this point is substantial, and in my original tab dashboard approach, I had organised all parts of the app code into specific folders. It was relatively simple to import functions into my "app.py" so that it had the minimal code necessary to instantiate the app. This helped me to organise and keep track. I aim to do something along the sames lines. I will play with your suggestions and see if I can meld the 2 approaches.

Comment: @AlexM Well, the single file isn't a requirement. When correctly modularized and imported, the above example would work the same. Especially with e.g. logging and production deployment (e.g. `gunicorn`) it can get a bit confusing but just instantiate the `app` Dash object once, right? And ensure import as needed. You may want to define the entire layout (even if it imports pages from other files) in a single file, and in another define the app with a single callback which renders by URL changes via `dcc.Location`. There are a number of options and descriptions around, as I'm sure you know